# Why do my project modules have the wrong versions?

Tags: angularjs, git, npm, bower

I'm building an AngularJS application. Everything is working fine but I discover that if I clone the repository for a clear new installation ALL the version of the module in /bower_components and /node_modules are different.

Some examples:

brand new cloned repository:

```
{
  "name": "angular-animate",
  "version": "1.5.7",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./angular-animate.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.7"
  }
}
```

Old repository:

```
{
  "name": "angular-animate",
  "version": "1.5.6",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./angular-animate.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.6"
  }
}
```

Even AngularJS itself:

New repository:

```
* @license AngularJS v1.4.12
```

Old repository:

```
  * @license AngularJS v1.4.10
```

That is happening for EVERY file in those two folders. How can I save all the current version of the bower and node modules and push that versions on my repository so everything would be okay for a fresh new installation?

EDIT:

This is my current bower.json file. What should I change in order to get specific versions of all AngularJS modules?

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-loader": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.0",
    "html5-boilerplate": "~5.2.0",
    "angular-payments": "*",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "webcam": "webcam-directive#^3.1.1",
    "angularjs-slider": "^2.14.0",
    "a0-angular-storage": "^0.0.15",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably has to do with how you've set up versioning in bower.json  Make sure you that you are configured for specific versions.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the question with my bower.json

Comment: Using the tilde ("~1.4.0") indicates you'll take any subsequent patch-level changes on the 1.4.x tree, starting with 1.4.0, but less than 1.5.0.  To specify an exact version format like this "1.4.10" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing:

```
"angular": "~1.4.0",
```

With:

```
"angular": "1.5.6",
```

Will keep version 1.5.6 even if a newer version is available

Answer (score 1):

Using the tilde ("~1.4.0") indicates you'll take any subsequent patch-level changes on the 1.4.x tree, starting with 1.4.0, but less than 1.5.0. To specify an exact version, simply remove the tilde and use the specific version number.

Instead of:

```
"angular": "~1.4.0"
```

Do this:

```
"angular": "1.4.10"
```